# typescript strict mode dynamically access different properties of different objects

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
const a = {
    type: "a",
    childrenA: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
} as const;

const b = {
    type: "b",
    childrenB: [ 4, 5, 6 ]
} as const;

const HIERARCHY = {
    a: "childrenA",
    b: "childrenB",
} as const;

const getChildren = <T extends typeof a | typeof b>(obj: T) => {
    const ret = obj[HIERARCHY[obj.type]];
    return ret;
};

const AOrB = Math.random() > 0.5 ? a : b;
getChildren(AOrB);
```

I have multiple objects of different types that all use a different key to store a common array, in this case `a` stores an array of numbers behind `childrenA` and `b` behind `childrenB`. I am trying to write a function `getChildren()` that can retrieve the common array from my objects. To know under which key the array is stored, there is the `HIERARCHY` object which maps the type of object to the relevant key.
The code for the is relatively simple, yet I am not sure how to type this in typescript strict mode.

I believe I understand the problem though.

- `obj.type` is of type `"a" | "b"`
- `HIERARCHY[obj.type]` is of type `"childrenA" | "childrenB"`
- accessing both `a["childrenA"]` and `b["childrenB"]` works, but I am not correctly telling ts that I will always access the correct property.

Comment: This is essentially [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), the recommended fix for which is described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves refactoring to indexed access into a "distributive object type", as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvKyRw).  Does this fully address your question and I can write up an answer (or find an appropriate duplicate) or am I missing something about your question?

Comment: Okay I'll put something here when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, the problem is that the compiler only sees that the types of `HIERARCHY[obj.type]` and `obj` are both [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but it doesn't have a way to represent the fact that they are *correlated* with each other.  It only knows that you want to index into an object of a type like `{childrenA: number[]} | {childrenB: number[]}` with an index of a type like `"childrenA" | "childrenB"`.  In general it's not valid to do this (e.g., `obj[HIERARCHY[Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : "b"]]`).  We know that if `obj` has a `"childrenA"` property, then `HIERARCHY[obj.type]` will be `"childrenA"`, but the compiler isn't tracking the *identity* of the expressions, just their *types*.

This is a general issue I've been calling "correlated union types", and is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  For a long time the only advice I had to give people was to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like

```
const getChildrenAssert = <T extends typeof a | typeof b>(
    obj: T): readonly number[] => (
        obj as unknown as Record<"childrenA" | "childrenB", readonly number[]>
    )[HIERARCHY[obj.type]];
```

But [microsoft/47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) suggested using a *distributive object type*, which is what you get when you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over a set of keys, and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with that set of keys.  That is, a type of the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]}`, where `K` is some keylike type (or union of such types), and `F<P>` is a type function that operates on keylike types.  Such a form ends up distributing `F<P>` over the union in `K`.  That is, if `K` is `K1 | K2 | K3`, then the distributive object type evaluates to `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`.

For your case, it could look like this:

```
type Mapper = typeof HIERARCHY;

type Obj<K extends keyof Mapper> = { [P in K]:
    { type: P } & Record<Mapper[P], readonly number[]>
}[K]
```

If we plug `"a"` into `Obj`, we get the type of your `a`:

```
type A = Obj<"a">;
/* type A = {
    type: "a";
} & Record<"childrenA", readonly number[]> */
```

and the same with `"b"`:

```
type B = Obj<"b">;
/* type B = {
    type: "b";
} & Record<"childrenB", readonly number[]> */
```

And if we plug in the union `"a" | "b"`, we get the union `typeof a | typeof b`:

```
type AOrB = Obj<"a" | "b">
/* type AOrB = ({
    type: "a";
} & Record<"childrenA", readonly number[]>) | ({
    type: "b";
} & Record<"childrenB", readonly number[]>) */
```

And now we make `getChildren()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that key type:

```
const getChildren = <K extends keyof Mapper>(
    obj: Obj<K>): readonly number[] => obj[HIERARCHY[obj.type]]; // okay
```

And there's no error at all.  The compiler sees `obj.type` as being of type `K`, and that generic type stays generic all throughout `HIERARCHY[obj.type]` and `obj[HIERARCHY[obj.type]]`.  The compiler sees the resulting output as assignable to `readonly number[]`, and everything works as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAEgSQKICUCCKDCcCaMC8MA3gLABQMlMAhgFwwBEwAFgJYA2AJgE4CmYaBgBpyVGACN6TNlz5gAQsPIBfGhBihIUANzlyUAJ4AHXjACy1Iye4EYhkyABm8ZOiy5dZfcdMB5cQBWADwA0jC8AB5Q-JzqANa8Bk7mltYAfLZEMADaAAowrGAwIQC6tKJUWfa89PmqAGQwKLyg3JxBFla83HklQjB81Jzg7AYwYACuALbi3dklaSrZpXpk1TBotv7BDNQMaZ4A9ABUdj4bmRWU1VJ7ng1NLSBtQdIcPPyC-YPDYKPj01mPQWMGOh1W63kW0Cr3E+yOp0hlwoVBujDh9xgjWarXab1k-EU314QxGY0mMzmILBEPOaF83ChhG2rz2MAAPuj9uQTmcTBsGUyYAAKUgo64+W4MTHYp4vfEfATCAYk37-ClA+ZpACUHJFYrEaIYGJUWMeuNeLHeciJKtJf3JgKpOtB4K8ZE00BoyMNksYexE4o0MkVaHo2QAjP0AEz9ADMJVN1HUnp05FTEh9qL9xqUQatBIU4YALP0AKz9ABsibIqmTGnA0E8qwzAHNeFBMCG5LZQuEojF4olkp10sKrjAQIF6CyQjr6D8yQDKcCCBkpwFsohUBhsDhshuAHTVEolZvuxwTMDAKCscD9ozsZ68AAqPggfci0TAsRgCSSzijt0aTChuM4wnOuoGlQR7rIchzFKaVAto2sD0oytgWFAzCHtw1A-iAUzCrqGQAAyHmWMAAPzevQ4ieBmABetjtp23b8MK6HyNq55McxhCsV21ocVUOYBsGwkCOG0YlDAyjaqs6aoTAgnsQIEAQN0sCEEEL79t+v7VMk1B6kZzjiCBE5gTAL7aguqpLhqVJriKE5iBuagwFecRgCAADuRT1jizx4gWoYMHqCo2sqi4OsumoLBO2pbq4u64AegTHj4p6eEAA)